# How to create a spreadsheet by email subject using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How could I go about automatically creating a spreadsheet every time I receive an email with a predetermined subject? After searching for a while, all I have found are tutorials that create an email by using a spreadsheet but I want to do the opposite of that. I have already tried using the getSubject() method and comparing it to my preset subject but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular, many samples and questions already show how to act on an email. other samples show how to create spreadsheets. show us what you tried (code)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that does this. Set a trigger to run it every 5 minutes (the interval can be changed, but then you should change the variable `interval` accordingly). It gets the recent threads in inbox, picks the subject of the first message in a thread, and matches it against "create spreadsheet NAME" syntax (NAME will be the name of created spreadsheet).

```
function ssFromEmail() {
  var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var timeFrom = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var subj = threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject();
    var match = subj.match(/^create spreadsheet (.*)$/i);
    if (match) {
      SpreadsheetApp.create(match[1]);
    }
  }
}
```